# Android Studio with Windows 10 to Windows 7

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10

I am using Windows 10 with Android studio installed. If I replace Windows 10 with Windows 7, Is there any method to copy all the files of Android studio after the new windows installation

Comment: Yes, there is. Copy them to a spare disk and after reinstallation, copy them back.

Comment: Have you tried copying all the files? However, I must say that Win7 is well past End of Support, and unless you have Extended Support, you really should not be using it. Assuming you have Extended Support, your probably shouldn't be asking this question here...

Comment: Yes , it worked thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy folders from C:\Users\%CurrentUser%

- .android
- .AndroidStudio3.1
- .config
- .cordova
- .derby-db
- .gradle
- .kettle
- .oracle_jre_usage
- .VirtualBox
- AndroidStudioProjects